# equivalent in perl of golang time.Unix( epoch + nanoseconds)

Tags: perl

On Golang I have the function Unix from time package with the following spec

https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.21.4#Unix

```
func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
```

It does

```
Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC
```

In other words, I am trying to decode a "datetime" from a given epoch in seconds + nanoseconds.

I find some alternatives to do the same in Perl such as

```
localtime($sec);
```

or using https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime I have the constructor `from_epoch`

but in any case, I can only parse seconds, not nanoseconds.

Is there a way to do it easily in Perl (with or without external modules) or should I ignore the nanoseconds part since it may be irrelevant?

Comment: [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) provides for nanoseconds in many ways.  Search the page for _nanosecond_, for example

Comment: But I don't know what you specifically need nanoseconds for.  Surely you aren't hoping for that level of actual precision or accuracy?

Comment: @zdim nanoseconds are just what you get when you want better-than-1s resolution in the 21st century.

Comment: @hobbs I don't know what they're hoping for with the term "nano."  Also, one can have any sub-second precision with [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns) (and other ways?), like `%3N` for miliseconds etc.  But what you say is indeed a good way to think about "nano"-seconds.

Comment: Well I wrote “DateTime” as anything (object, number, tuple, etc) that can be used as  DateTime such as the DateTime class itself. Anything that I can compare with others objects of same kind and can be nicely converted as string.

Comment: Comparisons are best done using the epoch times, though?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question correctly, it can be written as follows:

> Given an a number of seconds since the Unix epoch (`$epoch_whole_secs`), and given a number of nanoseconds since that second (`$epoch_nanosecs`), how do I obtain the local-time components (Y, m, d, H, M, S, ns) of the time that represents?

Using `localtime`:

```
my ( $S, $M, $H, $d, $m, $Y ) = localtime( $epoch_whole_secs );
$m += 1;
$Y += 1900;
my $ns = $epoch_nanosecs;
```

One could get a string representation using the following:

```perl
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $dt_text =
   ( strftime( "%FT%T", $S, $M, $H, $d, $m-1, $Y-1900 )
   . sprintf( ".%09d", $ns )
   );
```

Using `DateTime`:

```perl
use DateTime qw( );

my $dt =
   DateTime
      ->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch_whole_secs, time_zone => "local" )
      ->set_nanosecond( $epoch_nanosecs );
```

One could get a string representation using the following:

```perl
my $dt_text = $dt->strftime( "%FT%T.%N" );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) library provides for nanoseconds in many ways.  Search the page for *nanosecond*, for example.

Since the question mentions epoch time perhaps see [hires_epoch](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Ehires_epoch)

```
# Construct DateTime object $dt w/ nanoseconds (or set them later)...
my $dt = DateTime->now->set_nanosecond($ns);

my $epoch_floating = $dt->hires_epoch();
```

Note their warnings about precision, what brings us to the question of what you actually want this for?  Surely you aren't hoping for that level of actual precision or accuracy?

---

A question came up of how to build an object from two numeric values, for epoch time and nanoseconds.  For example

```
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch)->set_nanosecond($ns); 
say $dt, ' and ', $dt->nanosecond;
```

(That `$epoch` and `$ns` are the said numerical values you have for that time.)

To try it out with a one-liner (a command-line program)

```
perl -wE'use DateTime; 
    my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => time)->set_nanosecond(1234); 
    say "$dt and ", $dt->nanosecond, " nanoseconds"'
```

Or use [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns) to print it

```
say $dt->strftime("%F %T.%9N");  # which is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%9N"
```

Can use a lesser precision that "nano," with `%3N` or such.

It's still not clear what the exact context is in which this sub-second support is needed...

Comment: The issue is: if I start with two numeric values (epoch seconds and nanoseconds) I ‘d like to create one object (such as a DateTime instance). But there is no constructor that accepts both. from_epoch does not like it. I have some ideas such as use the timestand and add, somehow, the nanoseconds, or use it to create another object that I can set nanoseconds.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj  I added an example that relates to what you say in the comment